# Node.js DocumentDB DocumentClient - how to create a collectionLink

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb

When using Node.js documentdb.DocumentClient I can easily create a database and a collection, but if all I want to do is query an existing collection how do I build the collectionLink that should be the 1st parameter in this line of code?
What should the collectionLink contain?

```
client.queryDocuments(collectionLink, "SELECT * FROM docs d WHERE d.Email = 'test@test.com'").toArray(function(err, results){});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DocumentCollection link is built on the format
`dbs/databaseId/colls/collectionId`

So if your `databaseId` was `MyDatabase` and your `collectionId` was `MyCollection` then the collectionLink would be:

`dbs/mydatabase/colls/mycollection`

Or more simply, you can use the DocumentClient you already have to build this for you:

```
var collectionLink = client.createDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, collectionId);
```

Comment: couldn't get node to recognise client.createDocumentCollectionUri, but building up the string worked fine, thanks